# script to discover if an IP address belongs to an IP range

Tags: linux, bash, ip, range, belongs-to

I'm new here.
I'm working on a script that has to tell me if a giving IP address belongs to a IP range, using bash scripting.
For example: 
starting from a big range like 10.103.240.0/20 I have to code a script in bash linux to discover if the ip 10.102.247.221 belongs to the range?
I know that the HostMin is 10.103.240.1 and the HostMax 10.103.255.254 but i don't know how to implement the comparison.
Do you have a suggestion please? I don't know where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This could work :

```
function checkInRange() {
 hostMin=$1
 hostMax=$2
 ip=$3

 for i in $(seq 4)
 do
   hMini=$(echo $hostMin | cut -d'.' -f$i)
   hMaxi=$(echo $hostMax | cut -d'.' -f$i)
   ipi=$(echo $ip | cut -d'.' -f$i)
   if [[ $ipi -gt $hMaxi || $ipi -lt $hMini ]]
   then
     echo "$ip not in $hostMin - $hostMax range"  
     return 1
   fi
 done
 echo "$ip in $hostMin - $hostMax range"  
 return 0
}

if [[ $(checkInRange $hostMin $hostMax $ip) -eq 0 ]] 
then
  # Do your stuff...
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This horse has been flogged many times, simply put it's most reliable to use a tool built for the job.  `ipcalc`, `nmap`, to name a couple.

To answer the `bash` part about "if it's within", you could list your range and use `grep`

For instance, using `nmap`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ipRange="$1"
singleIP="$2"

nmap -sL -Pn -sn -n "$ipRange" \
| grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" \
| if (grep -q "$singleIP"); then 
    echo "In Range"
else 
    echo "Not in range"
fi
```

Unit tests

```
19:08:40 ツ :~ >./script.sh 10.103.240.0/20 10.102.247.221
Not in range

19:10:02 ツ :~ >./script.sh 10.103.240.0/20 10.103.241.111
In Range
```

Comment: this is very useful but i'll use the fzd's script because nmap takes more time. In any case I learned something more about nmap. I'm courious about ipcalc. I saw the ipcalc manual but i didn't find the options useful to my case. How could you do it using ipcalc?

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the dots from the IP and compare the numbers

```
#!/bin/bash

export IFS="."
function convertToNumber() {
    ipNumber=""
    for i in $1; do
        part="$i"
        while [ ${#part} -lt 3 ]; do
            part="0${part}"
        done
        ipNumber="${ipNumber}${part}"

    done
    echo ${ipNumber}
}

ip=$(convertToNumber "12.3.4.5")
min=$(convertToNumber "1.20.0.0")
max=$(convertToNumber "1.39.255.255")

if [ $ip -ge $min ] && [ $ip -le $max ]; then
    echo "${ip} is in range $min - $max"
else
    echo "${ip} is not in range $min - $max"
fi
```

Comment: Should `12.3.4.5` be in `1.20.0.0-1.39.255.255` range?

Comment: You are right. I would have to prefill with some 0es to make the number equal length.